# What does it mean to normalize based on mean and standard deviation of images in the imagenet training dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, imagenet

In implementation of densenet model as in [CheXNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05225.pdf) paper, in section 3.1 it is mentioned that:

> Before inputting the images into the network, we downscale the images to 224x224 and **normalize based on the mean and standard edviation of images in the ImageNet training set**.

1. Why would we want to normalize new set of images with mean and std of different dataset?
2. How do we get the mean and std of ImageNet dataset? Is it provided somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting the mean centers the input to 0, and dividing by the standard deviation makes any scaled feature value the number of standard deviations away from the mean.

Consider how a neural network learns its weights. C(NN)s learn by continually adding gradient error vectors (multiplied by a learning rate) computed from backpropagation to various weight matrices throughout the network as training examples are passed through.

The thing to notice here is the "multiplied by a learning rate".

If we didn't scale our input training vectors, the ranges of our distributions of feature values would likely be different for each feature, and thus the learning rate would cause corrections in each dimension that would differ (proportionally speaking) from one another. We might be over compensating a correction in one weight dimension while undercompensating in another.

This is non-ideal as we might find ourselves in a oscillating (unable to center onto a better maxima in cost(weights) space) state or in a slow moving (traveling too slow to get to a better maxima) state.

Original Post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185853/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-the-images-before-we-put-them-into-cnn

Answer (score 0):

They used mean and std dev of the ImageNet training set because the weights of their model were pretrained on ImageNet (see Model Architecture and Training section of the paper).